# Is the partial specilization of const _Tp* in stl_iterator_base.h in STL necessary

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

This is the code:

```
template <class _Iter>
inline typename iterator_traits<_Iter>::value_type*
__value_type(const _Iter&)
{
  return static_cast<typename iterator_traits<_Iter>::value_type*>(0);
}
```

The function reutrn the value_type* of _Iter.

This is the partial specilization of const _Tp*

```
template <class _Tp>
struct iterator_traits<const _Tp*> {
typedef random_access_iterator_tag iterator_category;
  typedef _Tp                         value_type;
  typedef ptrdiff_t                   difference_type;
  typedef const _Tp*                  pointer;
  typedef const _Tp&                  reference;
```

};

Is the partial specilization of const _Tp* necessary?, If we call

```
__value_type(const _Iter&)
```

we call

```
iterator_traits<_Iter>
```

without const actually.

```
iterator_traits<const _Iter>
```

will never happen.

Comment: The C++ standard does not mandate any particular implementation. This isn't a question about C++ as much as it is a question to your vendor.

Comment: if `_Iter` is `const char*` (for example) then yes, you will use this specialization. (It's a pointer to const, not a const pointer)

Comment: @KerrekSB I get it ,thank you!

Comment: @immibis you are right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the uses of `std::iterator_traits<T>` is determining the `value_type` in algorithms. The specialization would be needed when a `T const*` is used as the iterator type. The `value_type` is the `const`-unqualified version of the pointee. The implementation *could* have chosen to use

```
template <typename T>
struct iterator_traits<T*> {
    using value_type = std::remove_cv_t<T>;
    // ...
};
```

instead of specializing for `T const*`.

Using the specialization for `T const*` has the neat effect that it may diagnose [illegal] attempts from users to specialize for a general `T const*`: without the standard library specialization user code specializing this class template for `T const*` would compile OK but have undefined behavior.